# How to convert rows to columns in indexed view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, left-join, indexing

I use OUTER JOIN to get values stored in rows and show them as columns. When there is no value, I show NULL in column.

Source table:

```
Id|Name|Value
01|ABCG|,,,,,
01|ZXCB|.....
02|GHJK|;;;;;
```

View:

```
Id|ABCG|ZXCB|GHJK
01|,,,,|....|NULL
02|NULL|NULL|;;;;
```

The query looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    b.Id,
    bABCG.Value AS "ABCG"
    bZXCB.Value AS "ZXCB"
    bGHJK.Value AS "GHJK"
FROM
    Bars b
    LEFT JOIN Bars bABCG ON b.Id = bABCG.Id and b.Name = 'ABCG'
    LEFT JOIN Bars bZXCB ON b.Id = bZXCB.Id and b.Name = 'ZXCB'
    LEFT JOIN Bars bGHJK ON b.Id = bGHJK.Id and b.Name = 'GHJK'
```

I want to remove LEFT JOIN because it's not allowed in indexed view. I tried replacing it with inner SELECT, but inner SELECT is not allowed also and UNION too. I can't use INNER JOIN because I want to show NULLs in view. What should I use?

Comment: have you tried to use `FROM bars b,bars b1,bars b2 where (b.id=b2.id and  b.name='asdfa') and (b.id=b2.id and b.name='sdaf') ....`

Comment: Yes but this does not return nulls.

Comment: Hint: if you're running into a restriction with a particular method not being allowed in an indexed view, it is *highly* likely that any other form you try (that produces the same result set) will also not be allowed. You're not going to be able to produce an indexed view with the shape you're describing.

Comment: Also, even if there was a workaround for the join issues (which as I say, I suspect there isn't), `DISTINCT` isn't allowed in an indexed view either.

Comment: `DISTINCT` can be removed, no problem. Thanks for noticing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you are going to be able to do is use inner joins to get the matches, then union with  the left joins and filter it to only return nulls.  This probably won't solve your problem.

I don't know the specifics of your system but I am assuming that you are dealing with performance issues, which is why you want to use the indexed view.  There are a few alternatives, but I think the following is the most appropriate.

Since you commented this is for a DW I am going to assume that your system is more intensive on reads than writes and that data is loaded into it on a schedule by an ETL process.  In this kind of high read/low write* situation I would recommend you "materialize" this view, which means when the ETL process runs, to generate the table with your initial select statement that includes the left joins.  You will take the hit on the write, then all your reads will be on par with the performance of the indexed view (you would be doing the same thing the indexed view would do, except in a batch instead of on a row by row basis).  If your source DB and DW are on the same instance this is a better choice than an indexed view b/c it won't affect the performance of the source system (indexed views slow down inserts).  This is the same concept as the indexed view because you take the performance hit on the insert to speed up the select.

I've been down this path before and come to the following conclusion:

> An indexed view is more likely to be *part* of the solution than the entire solution.

*when I said "high read/low write" above you can also think of it as "high read/scheduled write"

Comment: Sorry I wasn't precise in that comment. My system is a **source** of data for DW. This indexed view was meant as a single place for DW to look for precalculated data. Data will be loaded from my system by DW in ~5 hrs intervals. I can't change DW.

Comment: After thinking about your PoV I think I just make this as regular view w/o index...

Comment: I think it makes sense for the ETL to take the performance hit once every 5 hours instead of your source system taking it on every insert.  A regular view seems appropriate here.

Answer (score 2):

You *may* be able to implement something similar using an actual table to store the results, and a set of triggers against the base tables to maintain the internal data.

I *believe* that, under the covers, this is what SQL Server does (in spirit, if not in actual implementation) when you create an indexed view. However, by examining the rules for indexed views, it's clear that the triggers should *only* use the `inserted` and `deleted` tables, and should not be required to scan the base tables to perform the maintenance - otherwise, for large tables, maintaining this indexed view would impose a *serious* performance penalty.

As an example of the above, whilst you can easily write a trigger for insert to maintain a `MAX(column)` column in the view, deletion would be more problematic - if you're deleting the current max value, you'd need to scan the table to determine the new maximum. For many of the other restrictions, try writing the triggers by hand, and most times there'll come a point where you need to scan the base table.

Now, in your particular case, I *believe* it could be reasonably efficient for these triggers to perform the maintenance - but you need to carefully consider all of the insert/update/delete scenarios, and make sure that your triggers actually faithfully maintain this data - e.g. if you update any `id`s, you may need to perform a mixture of updates, inserts and deletes.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    b.Id,
    (Select bABCG.Value from Bars bABCG where b.Name = 'ABCG')  AS "ABCG"
    ...
FROM
    Bars b
```

you may have to add a aggregation on the value, I'm not sure how your data is organized

Comment: This was my first try. But as I wrote in question, inner SELECT (subqueries) are not allowed in order to create indexed views in MSSQL ("Cannot create index on view because it contains one or more subqueries. Consider changing the view to use only joins instead of subqueries. Alternatively, consider not indexing this view.").

Comment: I dont think you can then! The "NULLs" will never be showed unless you use some sort of left join. On another topic, may I ask why do you need to index the view? Do you know that when you do that you persist the view's data on the DB? YOu basically have a copy of the data you already have?

Comment: This is data warehouse scenario so using indexed view is reasonable I think.

Comment: well it depends on several factors but it can be worst due to the large amount of data the index view would create

Comment: Yes, but i really want to make this indexed view. Maybe shoud I use CASE or PIVOT? I don't have experience with these.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - really? Isn't listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx

Comment: @Pol - it is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432(v=sql.90).aspx). As I said in my comment to your question, if you find yourself stymied using one approach, it's highly likely you'll be stymied by all approaches that produce the same result set.

Comment: You could build a procedure. I think you are having misconceptions about what a index view can do. The word "index" is tricking you :)